# Blocking invalid HTML not formatted as code?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Invalid HTML markup that isn't formatted as code in questions and answers just silently gets ignored. It makes many submissions that do not format code properly look like they were ran over by a steamroller. C and C++ code, especially, suffer. Submitters often have no idea that something went wrong, as they don't proofread the rendered submission.

I propose submissions should be checked for HTML syntactic validity, and for having no tags or attributes outside of a small agreed-upon subset. If this check fails, the submission should not be accepted, a and a link to formatting help should be presented to the user. For example:

```
  At line 23:
  #include <iostream>
  Unknown HTML tag 'iostream'. 
  If this is a code fragment, please format it accordingly (see this help page).
  A list of HTML tags allowed on stackoverflow is here.
```

Was something like this proposed before? Any reasons why it should not be implemented?

Comment: Four spaces do the magic!

Comment: This would only palliate the underlying problem (that is, lots of people don't know how to format properly) in a small subset of cases. But +1 anyway. Long live draconian errors and "fail early and fail loudly".

Comment: My knee-jerk assumption is that you were trying to prevent users from submitting code fragments that contained invalid HTML. Obviously that would largely make asking questions about HTML impossible.

Comment: @Oriol This small subset is especially bad because parts of what should be code are just invisible. Fortunately this makes these cases relatively easy to catch.

Comment: *Submitters often have no idea that something went wrong, as they don't proofread the rendered submission.* ... and that's something the UI needs to fix? It seems like the back of our heads are hitting our heels with how far we're bending over backwards for users who can't help themselves...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Preventing people from posting certain crappy-formatted posts would be a side-effect. Why I think this would be useful is because if I purposely attempt to use HTML code, but the element is not supported by StackOverflow, I would like to be warned.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't see it this way. If many new users are making the same mistake over and over again, then perhaps at least some part of the blame doesn't lie with the users.

Comment: I don't really buy that. A lot of new users don't include the error message when complaining about code that doesn't work. Is that a problem for Stack Overflow to solve? I don't think so, I think that's solely a failing of the people who are posting the questions. It's just plain logic; if you're going to ask why you're getting an error, post the error message. Likewise, when you're posting a question *read it*. But I keep forgetting that this site is no longer for "programmers" (who would presumably know logic); it's for anyone who can type something into a box.